# I have a new passport. What to do with regards to my UK visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, passport

I moved to the UK last year because of work. I have recently had a new passport this year, because my previous passport was expiring. Do I need to have the UK visa sticker on my new passport as well? Is there anyone I need to inform about my new passport? My UK visa is valid for three years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Home Office, it is not required to transfer your visa, although you can if you want (it costs money to do so). See [Transfer your visa to a new passport](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa) for more information.

> You don’t have to transfer your visa - you can carry both your old and new passports when travelling to or from the UK instead.